# $\ln (1 + x) <x $ using graph with which the natural logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Using the graph with which the natural logarithm ln is geometrically defined, show that $\ln (1 + x) <x$.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything to solve this? Like, maybe, draw the graphs in question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try using mathjax to make your question more presentable.

Comment: try the function $$f(x)=x-\ln(x+1)$$

Comment: Do you mean $\ln x = \int_1^x dt/t$?

Comment: Draw the hyperbola $xy=1$, and the horizontal line $y=1$. Starting at the point $(1,1)$ where both meet, the hyperbola remains below the horizontal line. Therefore the area below the first is less than the are below the second.

Answer (score 3):

First, it can be helpful to have a picture:

[image]

In this picture, the purple/blue area is the area below the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$ from $1$ to about 6.25, i.e. $\ln(1+5.25)$, while the red area is the area under curve $y=1$ over the same range, i.e. which is about $5.25$.  The [Desmos demos is linked here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) if you would like to play with this a bit more.

Generalizing this static picture, the red area represents $x$, while the blue area is $\ln(1+x)$.  From the picture, it seems clear which is larger.

Being a bit more careful, we can work symbolically, using the definitions directly: for any $x > 0$, we have
$$ \ln(x) := \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t. $$
This implies that
$$ \ln(1+x) = \int_{1}^{1+x} \frac{1}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t. $$
On the other hand, observe that
$$ x = \int_{1}^{1+x} 1 \,\mathrm{d}t; $$
that is, thinking of the integral as an area, we can regard $x$ as the area of a rectangle of height 1 and width $x$, with the lower-left corner at the point $(1,0)$.  But if $x > 1$, then we have $\frac{1}{x} < 1$, and so by the monotonicity of the integral, we have
$$ \log(1+x) = \int_{1}^{1+x} \frac{1}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t \le \int_{1}^{1+x} 1 \,\mathrm{d}t = x, $$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Yup. I find that most properties of the log can be easily derived from the integral definition.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ is a concave function and $y=x$ is a tangent line to $f$ in $(0,0)$.

Thus, $f(x)\leq x$ for all $x>-1$. Draw it!